# What is Vaijayanti Mala?

Tags: krishna

What are the uses and significance of Vaijayanti Mala? Is it only offered to lord Krishna?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.amazon.in/Parashara-Vaijanti-Mala-White/dp/B010CYY96O) the one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/vaijayanti-mala):

> Vaijayanti-mālā (वैजयन्ति-मल):—The garland made of five types of
>   forest flowers (or five jewels) is called the vaijyanti-mālā the
>   garland-of-victory. It symbolizes the five spheres of the senses, the
>   display of manifestation which surrounds the Supreme Being.
>
> pañca-rūpā tu yā mālā vaijayantī gadābhṛtaḥ | sā bhūta hetu saṃghāto
>   bhūtamālā ca vaidvija ||
>
> The necklace of the lord called Vaijayanti comprised of five precious
>   gems, (pearl, ruby, emerald, sapphire and diamond) is the aggregate of
>   the five elemental spheres. (V.P. 1;22;72.)

The  Vaijayanti-mālā is used for propitiating Lord Vishnu, Krishna and Rama. 
All these deities wore this mālā. The beads of this mālā originate from a 
forest where the divine beings are enthralled in eternal love. It is a 
bead of attraction, victory and attainment. The wearer of this mālā does 
not suffer losses and gets wish fulfillment. The rosary is made up of 108+1 
beads interspersed by knots.

Also refer **[CC Antya 15.66](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/antya/15/66)**:

> saudāminī pītāmbara, sthira nahe nirantara, muktā-hāra baka-pāṅti
>   bhāla indra-dhanu śikhi-pākhā, upare diyāche dekhā, āra dhanu
>   vaijayantī-māla

which means:

> “Kṛṣṇa’s yellow garments look exactly like restless lightning in the
>   sky, and the pearl necklace on His neck appears like a line of herons
>   flying below a cloud. Both the peacock feather on His head and His
>   **vaijayantī garland** [containing flowers of five colors] resemble
>   rainbows.

**[SB 10.29.44](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/29/44)**

> upagīyamāna udgāyan  vanitā-śata-yūthapaḥ mālāṁ bibhrad vaijayantīṁ
>    vyacaran maṇḍayan vanam

Meaning:

> As the gopīs sang His praises, that leader of hundreds of women sang
>   loudly in reply. He moved among them, wearing His Vaijayantī garland,
>   beautifying the Vṛndāvana forest.

**So yes it's offered to Lord Vishnu plus his incarnations.**

Some of the other types being worm by different deities are: Vanamālā, Mund-mālā of Siva Rudraksha-mālā.

Comment: but why it's written mala (मल) ? mala means impurity ..it should be mAlA (garland)

Comment: @Rickross probably it should be mālā not mala, your thoughts?

Comment: yes it should be mAlA